# Script skips reading text file

Tags: batch-file, command-line, command-prompt

I have the path to a text file stored in a variable like so:

```
set readfile="%USERPROFILE%\Utilities\list_2.txt"
```

I use a for loop to read it like this:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%i IN (%readfile%) DO
```

The problem is, it doesn't read the file, it skips the for loop altogether. The only way it can read the file is if I plug in the path directly, no variable in it's place. I've tried `!readfile!` as well, but it doesn't work, same result.

Comment: Usually a best practice to not store the quotes in your variable and surround the variable with quotes when you are using it.

Comment: `%readfile%` contains quotes, so it is not interpreted as a file name but as a literal string which is parsed by `for /F`; add the `usebackq` option to interpret it as file name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FOR /F "usebackqtokens=1" %%i IN (%readfile%) DO
```

or

```
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%i IN ('type %readfile%') DO
```

should fix your problem.

See `for /?|more` from the prompt for documentation.